# Prove $[x/4]_2$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Show that f: $4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$, $f(x)=[x/4]_2$, is a group homomorphism.

I have been trying without much luck to prove this. I have considered individual cases, but noticed the following:

Let $ a,b \in 4\mathbb{Z}$ where 8 divides neither a nor b. 
Then $f(ab)=[0]_2$,
 but $f(a)f(b)=[1]_2 [1]_2 = [1]_2$

So $f(ab)\neq f(a)f(b)$

Am I making a mistake here, or did I disprove what I am supposed to prove? Any help or insight would be great, thanks!

Comment: It has to be a group homomorphism regarding "+"

Comment: Notice, that $4\mathbb{Z}$ is not a group with multiplication, since it has no neutral element in that case. $1\notin 4\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Of course, thank you! It seems my most common mistakes are my oversights.

Comment: I suppose you've already managed to prove this statement. However if not, one easy way would be to realize that your map $f$ is the composition of two "obvious" homomorphisms.

Comment: I did manage to figure it out once I realized my mistake. That's a good tip though, perhaps I'll attempt it again with your approach!